# Plural or Singular + (s) in title name for dropdown fields

Tags: input-fields, dropdown, title

When designing dropdown fields for users that can hold 1 or more values, would you suggest to use the plural form of the title word, or the singular form followed by a (s).

Example 1: Teams

Example 2: Team(s)

In my opinion, the first example implies that the user can select multiple values. On the other hand, the second example shows that a user can also just select 1 value, but it looks not as clean as the first example.

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the plural form especially if you anticipate your users selecting multiple values over time. Also looks cleaner (just as you mentioned) and would fit perfectly when the user eventually selects multiple values.

Comment: Agreed. If multiple are supported, then use plural. "Teams" shows the user that they will find all of their teams there. If there's only one, no problem, but the user still knows that there can be multiple. On the other hand, "Profile" communicates that they can only have a single profile.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I will go with the plural form :D